# AngularJS 1.5 config delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, delayed-execution, typescript1.8, angularjs-config

I am learning AngularJS and TypeScript and built a very basic application to get myself going.

An application, that loads a element-directive onto a page, very simple, but I keep hitting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'directive' of null" when trying to load the directive hook.

I understand why this happens, but I cannot find any information on the internet on how to fix this.

The TS for reference:

**app.ts**

```
namespace playground.core
{
    "use strict";

    export let playgroundApp: ng.IModule = angular.module("playgroundApp", []);
    export let compileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider = null;

    playgroundApp.config(($compileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider, $controllerProvider: ng.IControllerProvider) => {
        (<any>$controllerProvider).allowGlobals();
        compileProvider = $compileProvider;
    }); 

    angular.element(document).ready(() => { angular.bootstrap(document, ["playgroundApp"]); });
}
```

**PlaygroundController.ts**

```
namespace playground.controllers
{
    "use strict";
    export interface IPlaygroundScope extends ng.IScope
    {

    }

    export class PlaygroundController
    {
        static $inject: string[] = ["$scope", "$element"];

        private scope: IPlaygroundScope;

        constructor($scope: IPlaygroundScope, $element: ng.IRootElementService)
        {
            this.scope = $scope;
        }
    }
}
```

**directive.ts**

```
namespace playground.directives
{
    "use strict";

    export interface ILoaderScope extends ng.IScope
    {

    }

    export class LoaderDirective
    {
        private scope: ILoaderScope;

        constructor($scope: ILoaderScope, $rootElement: ng.IRootElementService, $attributes: ng.IAttributes, $compile: ng.ICompileService)
        {
            this.scope = $scope;
        }
    }

    playground.core.compileProvider.directive.apply(null, ["loader", ["$compile", ($compile: ng.ICompileService) =>
    {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "template.html",
            scope: {

            },
            link: ($scope: ILoaderScope, $rootElement: ng.IRootElementService, $attributes: ng.IAttributes) =>
            {
                return new LoaderDirective($scope, $rootElement, $attributes, $compile);
            }
        };
    }]]);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="App_Themes/Designer/designer.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="playground.controllers.PlaygroundController">

    <div k2-loader=""></div>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="scripts/go-debug.js"></script>

    <script src="core/app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/PlaygroundController.js"></script>
    <script src="directives/loader/directive.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        "use strict";        

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The exception is thrown in directive.ts: **playground.core.compileProvider**.directive.apply... because there seem to be a delay on **playgroundApp.config(...)** which only gets called after the directive has already been loaded.

Is there a way to make this scenario work, without having to wrap the directive call in a **setTimeout(...)**?

Update:

So I ended up wrapping the directive portion in a check, and using setTimeout anyways, as there seems to be no other solution.

```
namespace playground.directives
{
    "use strict";

    export interface ILoaderScope extends ng.IScope
    {

    }

    export class LoaderDirective
    {
        private scope: ILoaderScope;

        constructor($scope: ILoaderScope, $rootElement: ng.IRootElementService, $attributes: ng.IAttributes, $compile: ng.ICompileService)
        {
            console.log("constructor");
            this.scope = $scope;
        }
    }

    let load = (): void =>
    {
        if (playground.core && playground.core.appCompileProvider)
        {
            playground.core.appCompileProvider.directive.apply(null, ["loader", ["$compile", ($compile: ng.ICompileService): ng.IDirective =>
            {
                return <ng.IDirective>{
                    restrict: "E",                  
                    templateUrl: "directives/loader/template.html",
                    scope: {
                    },
                    link: ($scope: ILoaderScope, $rootElement: ng.IRootElementService, $attributes: ng.IAttributes): LoaderDirective =>
                    {
                        return new LoaderDirective($scope, $rootElement, $attributes, $compile);
                    }
                };
            }]]);
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout(load);
        }
    };

    load();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
namespace playground.core
{
    "use strict";

    export let playgroundApp: ng.IModule = angular.module("playgroundApp", []);
    export let compileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider = null;

    playgroundApp.config(($compileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider, $controllerProvider: ng.IControllerProvider) => {
        (<any>$controllerProvider).allowGlobals();
        compileProvider = $compileProvider;
    }); 

    angular.bootstrap(document, ["playgroundApp"]);
}
```

you shouldn't have to rely on document loading to bootstrap angular.  perhaps, that's delaying the process.

Comment: thanks for this, unfortunately the delay persists. from what I've read, this is just the way the config works